# C program skips lines when entering capital letters?

Tags: c

So when I run the program if I input "Yes" for the first question it prompts what kind of dealership is this. I'm able to run through the whole program correctly prompting all the `printf` statements only if I input non capital letters. For instance:

```
Yes  
bartow ford  
wash  
brian cox  
ford explorer (if i input 2001 ford explorer it skips the next two printf statements idk why)

etc. etc.
```

But if i use capital letters such as

```
Bartow Ford.
```

it skips past the `printf`. What type of work does it need?
I understand some of the context is poor but I first worry about structure , then going back and making the language "pretty" 
My idea here is to allow a user to input where the car came from what dealership it came, from what needs to be done to the car, the cars owner, make model etc. etc., then any other information. Then its saved into a separate file on my desktop.
Thank you guys so much for any information!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define WASH 20
#define WAX 30
#define FULL 100
#define MINI 40
#define TINT 60

int main() {

    int exit;

    char type[40];
    char car[40];
    char name[40];
    char work[40];
    char dealer[40];
    char comments[200];

    float total;

    FILE *elite;

    elite = fopen("/Users/BlakePatterson/Desktop/Elite Detail/Customer.txt", "w");

    printf(".\nIs this a dealer car or is this a customer car?.\n");
    scanf("%s", type);

    if (strcmp(type, "Yes") == 0) {

        printf("What is the name of the dealership?.\n");
        scanf(" %s", dealer);

        printf("What type of work needs to be done to the car?\n\n 1.Wash.\n2.Wax.\n");
        scanf("  %s", work);

        printf("Please input the name of the person handling the car.\n");
        scanf("   %s", name);

        printf("Please input the make, model, year and condition of the car upon arrival.\n");
        scanf("    %s", car);

        printf("Do you need to make any more commentd?.\n");
        scanf("     %s", comments);

        printf("Are you finished? if so press 2 if not press 1.\n");
        scanf("%d", &exit);
    }

    fprintf(elite,"%s%s%s%s%s", dealer, work, name, car, comments);
    fclose(elite);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should "skip" there as soon as you have any *whitespace* following another word. `%s` only parses up to the first *whitespace*. Maybe you're interested in my [beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for more reliable input.

Comment: And by the way, `%s` will never stop parsing if there is *no whitespace*, so it will eventually overflow *any* buffer. Never use `s` and other conversions to a string with `scanf()` without an explicit *field width* (in your case: write `%39s` for parsing to a 40-byte buffer)

Comment: Although it may not be related, You should not use the identifier `exit`.

Comment: How is "Yes" an appropriate answer to "Is this a dealer car or is this a customer car?"?

Comment: At Felix Palmen. I read through your beginners guide away from scanf() thank you so much for that. The only thing confusing me is what exact is stdin in fgets? I set up the new code as : printf("what is the name of the dealership.\n"); fgets(dealer,40,stdin);

Comment: @stackptr lol hey man like I said I wasn't worried about the actually context language in printf. I meant to write is this a dealer car. When I saw it I chose not to fix because I had bigger problems.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yea I did notice that when using it as a variable that it might not be a good idea. Sorry the code is primitive and many changes will be made but the reading of the strings and it skipping lines when there's an input of two words is my biggest problem at the moment.

Comment: Granted guys I'm 1/4 the way through my intro to c class. I started enjoying programming so much I started watching c, python, html, css via the new Boston. I'm obviously overstepping my knowledge at the moment but I think I can make a lot of useful programs for my friends if I can figure out how to allow them to input something like "2001 red explorer" then that is saved to a file via the same directory on my desktop or theirs for that matter. Also is it possible to have a variable for the file name? Such as I ask the user what do u want to call this file? They say 2001 Ford Explorer blah."

Comment: given this prompt: "printf(".\nIs this a dealer car or is this a customer car?.\n");" what it the user expected to do? if the user enters 'dealer', the program has a seg fault event.  The question does not have a Yes/No answer.  the key is 'dealer' or 'customer'.  No where does it expect to be answered with 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: the posted code contains many 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis. IE. 40, 200 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest the lengths of the arrays be given meaningful names then those meaningful names used throughout the code.

Comment: the variable 'exit' is the same as a well known system function 'exit()' it is poor programming practice to use the same names for local variables as the system function names.

Comment: have you compiled the posted code?  the variable 'total' is not used.  it is poor programming practice to have variables taking up space (in this case on the stack) that are not used by the program.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the '%s' input conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer.  Otherwise the user can easily overrun the input buffer, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: this prompt: `Do you need to make any more commentd?.\n` (notice the misspelling of 'comments' ) This question can by answered with a Y/N but is actually trying to input a sentence.  Perhaps some rewording of the prompt, similar to: 'Please input an clarifying comments.'

Comment: this line: `scanf("%d", &exit);` is expecting the user to enter an integer.  But the user could enter anything.  If the user enters anything other than  an integer, the call to `scanf()` will fail.  And the results of that call to `scanf()` is not used within the posted code.

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  Otherwise, like happened on my system, where the call to `fopen()` failed, the call to `fprintf()` will cause a seg fault event.

Comment: when you want to input a multi word string, suggest using something like: `scanf( "%39[\n]", name );` as that will keep inputting characters until a newline is encountered. I.E. it will not stop consuming characters because it encountered a space, tab, etc; unless the 39 characters have been entered, then it will stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observe has nothing to do with capital letter, but rather with answers with multiple words. You cannot read multiple words with `scanf(" %s", dealer);`.  The initial space is redundant as `%s` skips any leading white space and reads a single word into the destination array. The following words will be read by subsequent calls to `scanf()` as answers for other questions.

You can either use `fgets(dealer, sizeof dealer, stdin)` and remove the trailing newline or use `scanf(" %39[^\n]", dealer);` to read multiple words on the same line upto 39 bytes.  The same holds for the other input lines, adjusting for the different array sizes.

Comment: Ok I'm going to do that and rewrite the program after work. Thanks a lot man. I do have another question if it's not too much. I got it to start a file at the directory of my choice but it comes up like bartowbrianwash. How can I get to say bartow "new line" Brian "new line" wash in the file it's being written to. Besides that I really appreciate the response.

Comment: @WatchTower: you should learn about `fprintf`. Use: `fprintf(elite,"%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n", dealer, work, name, car, comments);`

Comment: awesome thanks man we just started fprintf in class. The scope of this class will more than likely only touch on storing integers into an exterior file.